# Textbox Prevent Space

Tags: php, textbox

```
<?php
$varray = $database->getProfileVillages($session->uid);
for($i=0;$i<=count($varray)-1;$i++) {
    echo "<tr><th>Köy ismi</th><td><input tabindex=\"6\" type=\"text\" name=\"dname$i\" value=\"".$varray[$i]['name']."\" maxlength=\"20\" class=\"text\"></td></tr>";
} 
?>
<tr><td colspan="2" class="desc2"><textarea tabindex="8" name="be2"><?php echo $session->userinfo['desc1']; ?></textarea></td></tr>
```

I want that if user enters " " (space) then system changes it to - (hiphen).

**Example**

("Soul Man" becomes "Soul-Man") & (" " becomes "-").

Can you replace code to my code please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use `str_replace()`

When giving `echo`, give this:

```
echo str_replace(" ", "-", $str);
```

Where `$str` is the string, in which you wanna replace the spaces to dashes.

---

#### Replace:

```
$varray[$i]['name']
```

#### With:

```
str_replace(" ", "-", $varray[$i]['name']);
```

---

#### Copy paste this code:

```
echo "<tr><th>Köy ismi</th><td><input tabindex=\"6\" type=\"text\" name=\"dname$i\" value=\"", str_replace(" ", "-", $varray[$i]['name']), "\" maxlength=\"20\" class=\"text\"></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Mate, im ameteur. Please help me, can you replace it?

Comment: @user1936293 Can you show the full code? Or if that's the full code, which is the thing to be replaced? Are you talking about the `textarea` thing?

Comment: I gave full code in my first message. I think we replace to: echo "<tr><th>Köy ismi</th><td><input tabindex=\"6\" type=\"text\" name=\"dname$i\" value=\"".$varray[$i]['name']."\" maxlength=\"20\" class=\"text\"></td></tr>";

Comment: Can you check my answer now?

Comment: I did: echo "<tr><th>Köy ismi</th><td><input tabindex=\"6\" type=\"text\" name=\"dname$i\" value=\""str_replace(" ", "-", $varray[$i]['name']);"\" maxlength=\"20\" class=\"text\"></td></tr>"; ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /data/multiserv/users/983553/projects/2346174/www/Templates/Profile/profile.tpl on line 54

Comment: Its working but i dont want this. Example user send "asdasd asda". This words go to sql but dont change to "asdasd-asda". But we see in profile "asdasd-asda". ???

Comment: Yeah, in DB it won't be saved with dashes.

Comment: So? How can i do it for DB?

Comment: Can you say what must i search in php's?

Comment: See something like `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: $name = str_replace(" ","-",$name); I added this code and working fine. Thank you for all helps. You're best :)

Comment: But now, if user dont write anything (""), we see space " ". What must i do now? :(

Comment: Don't allow the user to submit the empty textbox then.